# get last item array pop

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have this array

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "lat": 31.135859,
      "lng": 46.823952,
      "hd": 319
    },
    {
      "lat": 31.050476,
      "lng": 46.907204,
      "hd": 320
    },
    {
      "lat": 30.999023,
      "lng": 46.957184,
      "hd": 320
    },
    {
      "lat": 30.955353,
      "lng": 46.999352,
      "hd": 320
    }
  ]
}
```

While I am try to get only last item from array above using `pop()` I get error like this:

> this.heading.pop is not a function

```
heading: [] = [];
for (let datas of getdata['data']) {
  this.heading = datas.hd;
  console.log("heading"+this.heading.pop());
}

this.heading.pop();
```

Comment: `heading` is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const item = array.data[array.data.length - 1].hd;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the *for* `loop` wrong. You could do this in a more simple way:

```js
let obj = { "data": [ { "lat": 31.135859, "lng": 46.823952, "hd": 319 }, { "lat": 31.050476, "lng": 46.907204, "hd": 320 }, { "lat": 30.999023, "lng": 46.957184, "hd": 320 }, { "lat": 30.955353, "lng": 46.999352, "hd": 320 } ] }

console.log(obj.data.pop().hd);
```

Comment: but l want getting `hd` from this array , i want always using last item hd from array

Comment: After using `pop` method the element is removed from the array.

Comment: If you want to keep it then use `obj.data[obj.data.length - 1].hd`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with this one:

```js
let obj = { "data": [ { "lat": 31.135859, "lng": 46.823952, "hd": 319 }, { "lat": 31.050476, "lng": 46.907204, "hd": 320 }, { "lat": 30.999023, "lng": 46.957184, "hd": 320 }, { "lat": 30.955353, "lng": 46.999352, "hd": 320 } ] }

console.log(obj.data.reduceRight(value => value).hd) // 320
```

I hope it's can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you were trying to do was pushing the "hd" headers to another array and get the last header. You can do it like below

```js
var obj = {
    "data": [
        {
            "lat": 31.135859,
            "lng": 46.823952,
            "hd": 319
        },
        {
            "lat": 31.050476,
            "lng": 46.907204,
            "hd": 320
        },
        {
            "lat": 30.999023,
            "lng": 46.957184,
            "hd": 320
        },
        {
            "lat": 30.955353,
            "lng": 46.999352,
            "hd": 320
        }
    ]
}

var heading = []

function getLast() {
    for (let datas of obj.data) {
        heading.push(datas.hd);
    }
    return heading.pop();
}

console.log(getLast());
```

There are more effective ways to do it. Those answers are already given.